# function output type varying with input

Tags: rust

I have a function like this, where the user of the function specifies the type of the output:

```
pub fn test(user_input: &str, number: f32) -> ??? {
    if user_input == "f32"{
        number as f32
    } else if user_input == "f64" {
        number as f64
    } else {
        panic!();
    }
}
```

I am rather new to Rust, so I ask you, how can I make this function return the type asked by the user? I am interested only in f32 and f64 outputs.

Comment: Why do you want to write such a function? How is it supposed to be used?

Comment: using for an audio decoder, where I want the user of the function to specify the precision.

Comment: Since this is related to audio, please have a look at how the cpal crate handles sample formats' various types: https://github.com/RustAudio/cpal/blob/master/examples/beep.rs#L85 It might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. Rust is statically typed language, so the type must be known at compile time. It cannot depend on user input.

What you could do instead is define a union type, like:

```rust
enum Float {
    Single(f32),
    Double(f64),
}
```

and then write

```rust
pub fn test(user_input: &str, number: f32) -> Float {
    if user_input == "f32"{
        Single(number as f32)
    } else if user_input == "f64" {
        Double(number as f64)
    } else {
        panic!();
    }
}
```

I don't see how such function would ever be useful though.

Update: Or you can create a common trait, but in return position you have to box it. Like:

```rust
trait Float { … }

impl Float for f32 { … }

impl Float for f64 { … }
```

and then write

```rust
pub fn test(user_input: &str, number: f32) -> Box<dyn Float> {
    if user_input == "f32"{
        Box::new(number as f32)
    } else if user_input == "f64" {
        Box::new(number as f64)
    } else {
        panic!();
    }
}
```

This makes sense for large objects (like whole buffer with associated codec), but for single values the overhead is relatively huge.

Comment: isn't there a way to make it work with a trait or generics?

Comment: @daniellga you could make a trait over the two types and use it dynamically, but in return position it requires boxing, which adds more overhead on top of the dynamic dispatch. Which might be sensible choice for large objects (like whole sound buffer with associated functions specialized for given format), but not for individual values.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to convert based on what the caller of the function needs, maybe try this:

```rust
fn t_from_f32<T: From<f32>>(f: f32) -> T {
    f.into()
}
```

Then you can call this function like this:

```rust
fn main() {
    let f = 1.0;

    // bind to a local variable with explicit types
    let double: f64 = t_from_f32(f);
    let float: f32 = t_from_f32(f);
    
    // .. or use turbofish syntax for the function call
    let turbofish_double = t_from_f32::<f64>(f);
}
```